# Comparar 2 linhas da mesma tabela

Tags: mysql

Preciso fazer uma consulta MYSQL. Tenho uma tabela em que possuo coluna "data_emissao" e "data_vencimento". Preciso achar todas as linhas em que elas possuem a mesma data de vencimento,mas diferentes datas de emissão. Como consigo comparar linhas assim de uma mesma tabela?
EX:

> ```
> Produto | data_emissao | data_venc
>    A    |  02/01/2016  | 02/01/2020
>    B    |  04/07/2013  | 02/01/2020
> ```

A consulta SQL deveria retornar a data vencimento 02/01/2020

Comment: Junção levando consideração que a data de vencimento é igual E data de emissão do produto a esquerda menor que o da direita?

Comment: A data de emissão pode ser tanto maior quanto menor, ou seja, apenas tem a condição de ser diferente.

Comment: @Christian se a resposta ajudou, por favor, marcar a resposta como útil e correta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue exemplo abaixo de como deve ser feito:

```
SELECT 
    T1.PRODUTO, T1.DATA_EMISSAO, T1.DATA_VENCIMENTO
FROM 
    TABELA T1
INNER JOIN 
    TABELA T2 ON T2.DATA_VENCIMENTO = T1.DATA_VENCIMENTO
WHERE 
    T1.DATA_EMISSAO <> T2.DATA_EMISSAO
```

Comment: No caso pelo que entendi só interessam as datas de vencimento. O resto poderia ser ignorado